# POST error because field "name" is not allowed to be duplicated in MongoDB table (nodeJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, web

In my website, I want to be able to create the same category name for different users.

Every time that I try to do it, I am getting the following error:

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: planit.categories index: name_1 dup key: { name: "1" } {
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { name: 1 },
  keyValue: { name: '1' },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

**BACKEND (nodeJS & expressJS)**
My Categories model (I do not specify unique: true for "name"):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userPrefixName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  tasks: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Task"
  }],
  createdBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  }
});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);

module.exports = Category;
```

The POST route:

```
// POST route ==>  Creates a new category
router.post("/categories/new", async (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    const createdBy = req.payload.user;
    try {
        // Fetch the user's username to use as a unique prefix
        const user = await User.findById(createdBy);
        const userPrefix = user.username;
        const userPrefixName = `${userPrefix}_${name}`;

        // Create the new category
        let response = await Category.create({
            userPrefixName,
            name,
            createdBy,
            tasks: []
        });

        return res.status(201).json(response);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
});
```

**FRONTEND (reactJS)**
Create new category:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import NavBar from '../Components/NavBar';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from '../config/vite.config';

function NewCategory() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [categoryName, setCategoryName] = useState('');

const handleCreateCategory = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const tokenInStorage = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
    const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/categories/new`, {
      name: categoryName
    }, {headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${tokenInStorage}`}});

    if (response.status === 201) {
      // Redirect to the task page for the new category
      navigate(`/categories`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};



  return (
    <div>
         <div className='header'>
     <div className="logo">
                <p>Plan<span>It</span></p>
         </div>
         <NavBar />
      </div>

      
      <h2>Create your new Category</h2>

      <form className="signFlex" onSubmit={handleCreateCategory}>
        <label>
          Category name:
          <input className="inputFlex"
            type="text"
            value={categoryName}
            onChange={(e) => setCategoryName(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </label>
        <button className="btn1" type="submit">Create</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NewCategory;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Somehow you have a unique index on field `"name"`.  If that's not what you want, you can delete/modify the index.

Comment: Perfect, it worked. Thanks! Can you explain to me why it uses name as an index instead of userPrefixName if I specified it to be the unique value from the schema?

Comment: I'm not sure it's related.  I'm not a _mongooser_, but perhaps there is another unique index on `"userPrefixName"`.  You can have many indexes per collection.  I don't know how a unique index on `"name"` was created - maybe when the collection was first created there was a different schema?

Comment: Yes, it must be that. At the beggining, we didn't think about having the `userPrefixName` so the `name` was the primary and unique key. So I guess that even though that the schema is changed on paper, there is something wrong on how the indexing of models are programed on mongoose

Comment: Yeah, I don't know mongoose's mechanisms for removing/modifying an index.  I wonder if setting `"unique": false` in the schema would modify the index.